# MySQL - get data from 2 tables similtanusly

Tags: mysql

alright so i've got two tables here, `gforum_Post` and `gforum_PostView`

i'm trying to get information from the table `gforum_Post` where it has the same post_id.

```
"SELECT post_subject, post_username FROM `gforum_Post` WHERE post_id = 341"
```

i've got it to display what i want but it's hard coded, the data in the columns will change. here's what i've got so far

```
SELECT post_id_fk, post_thread_views FROM `gforum_PostView` ORDER BY `gforum_PostView`.`post_thread_views` DESC

SELECT post_subject, post_username FROM `gforum_Post` WHERE post_id = 341
```

341 is the value that is hardcoded

Comment: The structure of the tables would be helpful

Comment: you need a JOIN. (INNER or LEFT). A little bit of search will help you to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join to join the tables:

```
SELECT post_id_fk, post_thread_views, post_subject, post_username FROM `gforum_PostView` 
join `gforum_Post` on post_id =post_id_fk
ORDER BY `gforum_PostView`.`post_thread_views` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the JOIN query:

```
SELECT GPV.post_id_fk, GPV.post_thread_views, GP.post_subject, GP.post_username 
FROM gforum_Post GP, gforum_PostView GPV 
WHERE GP.post_id = 341
ORDER BY GPV.post_thread_views DESC
```